# Modifying a MP4's "standard" parameter (from NTSC to PAL) with ffmpeg

Tags: windows-7, ffmpeg, standards

I have some MP4s encoded with the Mainconcept H264 encoder at resolution 1920x1080 with framerate 25fps interlaced top-field first. MediaInfo reports these files having a (video format) standard of "NTSC" which is incorrect. Can FFMPEG modify this parameter without re-encoding?
I have tried to use the -tvstd option which FFMPEG tells me to use the -standard option instead. Trying the -standard option (in versions 2.8.4 and N-86691-gc885356) however always returns an error of "Unrecognized option". Can someone please clarify this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: At such resolutions, I doubt "PAL" would be correct either... Any specific reason you need to change this?

Comment: Hi grawity, my intention was to change the standard to either "undefined" or "PAL". The playback destination is a TV with built-in USB reader but it seems to only recognize MP4s properly when their framerate matches their standard or when the standard is "undefined".

Comment: Those are color property tags. Let me check if those can be changed without re-encoding. `-standard` will have no effect.

Comment: Hi Mulvya, I've had success with hex editing various metadata atoms in the MP4s. Would it be possible to hex edit the H264 bitstream?